# Why does external API using CloudFront returns status code 403 on different locations

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, curl, https, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to integrate an external API that seems to be hosted in AWS, and so far I've experienced different overall responses depending from where I make the request. Locally it works fine, but when I try it in production I always get the same response: `{ "message": "Forbidden" }`.

I've tried hitting the API usign CURLs from different places and the results are arbitrary:

- Making the request from 2 different servers that run the same OS, one works and the other one doesn't.
- Making the request from Google Cloud doesn't work, from GitHub actions doesn't work, from AWS it does work.

This is my first time experiencing something like this so I'm open to giving any useful information to find the solution.

It's worth noting that I don't have any administrative permissions on the API, I'm just a consumer.

Here's some CURLs responses I got:

**Valid**

```
curl --verbose --location 'https://external-api.com/endpointpath' --header 'User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.32.2' --header 'x-api-key: apikey' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{}'
*   Trying xx.xx.xx.xx:xxx...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to external-api.com (xx.xx.xx.xx) port xxx (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=external-api.com
*  start date: May  7 00:00:00 2023 GMT
*  expire date: Jun  4 23:59:59 2024 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "external-api.com" matched cert's "external-api.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Amazon; CN=Amazon RSA 2048 M02
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0xxxxxxxxxxxxx)
> POST /endpointpath HTTP/2
> Host: external-api.com
> accept: */*
> user-agent: PostmanRuntime/7.32.2
> x-api-key: apikey
> content-type: application/json
> content-length: 2
>
* We are completely uploaded and fine
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 128)!
< HTTP/2 200
< content-type: application/json
< content-length: 345
< date: Tue, 26 Sep 2023 14:20:19 GMT
< x-amzn-requestid: requestid
< x-amz-apigw-id: apigw-id
< x-amzn-trace-id: traceid
< x-cache: Miss from cloudfront
< via: 1.1 3.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
< x-amz-cf-pop: cfpop
< x-amz-cf-id: amzcfid
<
* Connection #0 to host external-api.com left intact
```

**Invalid**

```
curl --verbose --location 'https://external-api.com/endpointpath' --header 'User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.32.2' --header 'x-api-key: apikey' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: */*' --header 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' --header 'Connection: keep-alive' --header 'Cache-Control: no-cache' --data '{}'
*   Trying xxx.xx.xx.xx...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to external-api.com (xxx.xx.xx.xx) port xxx (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Unknown (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=external-api.com
*  start date: May  7 00:00:00 2023 GMT
*  expire date: Jun  4 23:59:59 2024 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "external-api.com" matched cert's "external-api.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Amazon; CN=Amazon RSA 2048 M02
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0xxxxxxxxxxxxx)
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
> POST /endpointpath HTTP/2
> Host: external-api.com
> User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.32.2
> x-api-key: apikey
> Content-Type: application/json
> Accept: */*
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
> Connection: keep-alive
> Cache-Control: no-cache
> Content-Length: 2
>
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
* We are completely uploaded and fine
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS updated)!
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
< HTTP/2 403
< content-type: application/json
< content-length: 23
< date: Mon, 25 Sep 2023 18:42:03 GMT
< x-amzn-requestid: requestid
< x-amzn-errortype: ForbiddenException
< x-amz-apigw-id: apigw-id
< x-cache: Error from cloudfront
< via: 1.1 a.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
< x-amz-cf-pop: cfpop
< x-amz-cf-id: amzcfid
<
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
* Connection #0 to host external-api.com left intact
```

I've checked that timdatectl are the same between servers that work and others that doesn't work.
Those two examples have different ip/port, but I have confirmed that depending on the location hitting the exact same ip/port from different locations has the exact same behaviour, sometimes it just works or I get Forbidden.